# SonarQube with Jenkins Error :Fail to download libraries from server

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I have updated Sonar to version 7.9.2 and now while trying to give build through Jenkins getting below error.

```
BUILD FAILED
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute SonarQube
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:100)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:87)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:87)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:83)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doStart(EmbeddedRunner.java:249)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.start(EmbeddedRunner.java:187)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.start(EmbeddedRunner.java:182)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.ant.SonarQubeTask.launchAnalysis(SonarQubeTask.java:66)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.ant.SonarQubeTask.execute(SonarQubeTask.java:55)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:758)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to download libraries from server
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.Jars.downloadFiles(Jars.java:93)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.Jars.download(Jars.java:70)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:40)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:91)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.Jars.downloadFiles(Jars.java:87)
        ... 28 more
```

Not able to understand which libraries are not getting downloaded.
Other Details
Apache Ant version 1.7.1
SonarQube Ant Task version: 2.4
sonarqube-7.9.2

**Also want to update that the default java version is 1.7.80 which is used to compile the source code whereas for running sonarqube java 11 is being used.**

Please suggest.

Let me know in case any additional details are required.

Comment: Try with the latest version `SonarScanner For Ant 2.7`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.Tried updating it.Now getting below error message
    
 java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonarsource/scanner/ant/SonarQubeTask : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Comment: Version 52.0 implies java 1.8. Can you use jdk 1.8 and specify source/target = 1.7?

Comment: Using the latest version of the SonarScanner worked for me, thanks @KarthikeyanVaithilingam!